What would mixing bleach with other household surfactants like dish liquid and floor cleaners?
What would exactly happen if I mixed bleach with surfactants like dishwashing liquid and or floor cleaning solutions? What kind of safety requirements or hazards are there? What should I be scared of for my health sake?


Personal health questions are off-topic. 2. Which cleaners? Each has a different composition, which would affect the answer.


What would exactly happen depends on the specific ingredients in the product you mix with bleach. There are two common types of cleaning products you shouldn't mix with bleach: (1) toilet cleaners containing hydrochloric acid; (2) ammonia cleaning solutions.
Bleach usually contains sodium hypochlorite, a strong oxidizing agent. When mixed with hydrochloric acid or ammonia, some chlorine gas will be generated. Chlorine gas is toxic and strongly irritates your respiratory system. When inhaling too much chlorine gas, one can even die.
By the way, the category you chose (physical chemistry) isn't accurate. This isn't really physical chemistry. Using hydrochloric acid as an example, the reaction would be: NaClO + 2HCl → NaCl + Cl2 + H2O.
If it's a cleaning product not containing hydrochloric acid or ammonia, then usually nothing would happen when you mix it with bleach, meaning it'll be safe unless there's some really atypical ingredients in it that can react with bleach to generate something else toxic (but you'll mostly likely never encounter that type of situation).
Example: if you mix bleach with hand soap, nothing happens.
Another example: if you mix bleach with toilet cleaner that doesn't contain hydrochloric acid, nothing happens.
One more example: if you mix bleach with regular detergent you use to wash clothes, nothing happens.
When I say nothing happens, I mean there's no significant danger. Some negligible chemical reactions can always happen.

This is a very broad answer, because the question is far too broad, and needs to be more specific. Also, if bleach is mixed with hand soap, particularly containing quaternary ammonium antimicrobials, there may indeed by reactions, e.g., formation of chlorinated organic compounds: https://www.forceflowscales.com/downloads/chemical-safety/hypochlorite/SodiumHypoIncompatibilityChart.pdf
